# How to work on micro frontend app that requires authentication in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

Currently, we have created a micro frontend application,

In there we are managing the authentication in the parent micro frontend and passing the access token as props to the children micro frontend for making the API calls etc...

[image: mfe]

But without the access token, the children's application can't make any API calls. In this case, there is no point in running the children's application separately. I require the parent application has also needed to be running in my local to work on the children's app.

This actually makes the Dashboard Service Frontend team to start the Parent Frontend application as well. They cant work separately on Dashboard Service Frontend because of the need for an access token.

Please suggest if is there any alternative way to work on the Child Application without the need of Parent Application.

Or this is how we have to work, I am new to this micro front end. A help/suggestion would be much appreciated

Comment: I understand you want to use one of the child frontends "stand-alone", so not in a micro-frontend setup? Package the authentication code as a node module that can be used by children. That's assuming there is no UI on the page required to make it work. If there is UI with user interaction required (login form or whatever), you cannot run the children outside of the micro-frontend scenario.

Comment: You could hardcode a dummy token in the child application during development. Or during development, mock the APIs using [msw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msw)